# Boolean query malformed

Tags: elasticsearch

Error message:
*'[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]')*

Query:

```
{'query':{
     'bool': {
          'must': {
               'bool': {
                    'should': [
                          {'match': {'title' : a[0]}},
                          {'match': {'title' : a[1]}}  
                              ],
                    'minimum_should_match': 1
                       }
                  }

                                           
              }
          },

 }
```

I have searched several questions but still can't figure out where in the query is wrong.

Update: It is totally my problem. I thought the mistake was on the boolean query so I removed some code I thought was not related in my original question. The actual query is like this:

```
search_body_try1 = {'query':{
                             'bool': {
                                 'must': {
                                     'bool': {
                                         'should': [
                                             {'match': {'title' : a[0]}},
                                             {'match': {'title' : a[1]}}  
                                                   ],
                                         'minimum_should_match': 1
                                             }
                                          }

                                           
                                     },
                              'sort':[{'_score': {'order':'desc'}},
                                      {'_id': {'order':'desc'}}]
                                 },
                            'size':200
                            }
```

Now it seems to me the problem is that the `'sort'` should be put outside `query`?

Comment: What do you replace `a[0]` and `a[1]` with? Which version of ES are you running?

Comment: ```a``` is a list of strings. ES version being used is 7.0.4

Comment: Are you doing exact matches on the title field?

Comment: yes I am trying to. Is there a difference to the boolean query doing exact matches/ not doing exact matches?

Comment: Can you show the query once it's generated and ready to be sent to ES? Can you stringify it after adding the parameters?

Comment: Just added an update FYI. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes, sort must be at the top level, it's probably the reason why

Answer (score 0):

The query was indeed malformed. `sort` needs to be at the same level as `size` and `query` — i.e. something along the lines of:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "title": a[0]
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "title": a[1]
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 200
}
```

If you have a `score` field, replace `_score` with `score`. Similarly with `_id`.